# Silverlight 3 out-of-browser: set host window size?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Is it possible for a Silverlight 3 application which is running in out-of-browser mode to set the size of the container window? I've got an app with collapsible panel sections and I want the window to automatically size to the current size of the LayoutRoot control.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the window size in the project settings:

1. Open Project settings
2. Open `Out of browser settings` in `Silverlight` Tab
3. Set the window size, window title or window position

Answer (score 3):

**I Agree with pivotnig This Is more Simplified version**

1 . Click On Sliverlight Project

2 . Select Properties option

3 . Select First tab option Like Silverlight

4 . Click On Out-Of-Browser setting Option

5 . Set the window size, window title or window position etc......