# SL5 out of browser main window size - preserving minimum

Tags: silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

We allow the user to resize the out-of-browser application, but we want to preserve a minimum size.

We handle the SizeChanged event like this:

```
        if (e.NewSize.Width < MINWIDTH)
        {
            App.Current.MainWindow.Width = MINWIDTH;
        }
        if (e.NewSize.Height < MINHEIGHT)
        {
            App.Current.MainWindow.Height = MINHEIGHT;
        }
```

Unfortunately, this causes some very unatractive flickering.
Are there any other techniques for setting a minimum size?

Thanks for any ideas....

Comment: you should reefer this link

[outofbrowser][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187431/silverlight-3-out-of-browser-set-host-window-size/14038629#14038629

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that addresses setting the initial size, not preserving a minimum size when the user resizes the window.